# C language mpirun running error from cygwin

Tags: c, cygwin, mpi, mingw, openmpi

I try to run an C language MPI program using cygwin environment (console). The compilation process works fine, but I get an error when I try to run the output program. What I configured by now:

- I use cygwin environment, here is the installed packages:
  [image]
- also, I downloaded and added mingw to the user path:
  [image]
- as you can see cygwin bin is also added to the path

But about the code - a simple piece of code

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
int rank, size;
MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size );
MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank );
printf( "Hello World! I am %d of %d\n", rank, size );
MPI_Finalize( );
return 0;
}
```

In the cygwin console, the compilation

```
mpicc file.c -o file
```

works fine and ends without any error. But the problem occurs when I try to run it with

```
mpirun -np 2 ./file
```

The error is:

```
[DESKTOP-3F9P53V:01959] [[INVALID],INVALID] FORCE-TERMINATE AT Not found:-13 - error /pub/devel/openmpi/v4.0/openmpi-4.1.5-1.x86_64/src/openmpi-4.1.5/orte/mca/plm/rsh/plm_rsh_component.c(335)
```

Looks like something is missing, but I don't know what. What other packages should I download? I reinstalled the openmpi package but no changes. Or the trouble comes from the versions of some cygwin packages ? (also, as a mention, the source for the packages is mirrors.kernel.org)

Comment: I don't understand.  Why tag C++?  Your post is about the C language.  They are distinct languages.  For example, C++ has function and operator overloading, C doesn't.  Are you mixing the languages?  Not advised unless necessary.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews you're right, sorry for this mistake

Comment: try installing the `openssh` package.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet after I installed openssh, the code runs now (I can see the prints in the console), but some things still have troubles; together with the effective output (from printf), the console also print:

Comment: PMIX ERROR: ERROR in file /pub/devel/openmpi/v4.0/openmpi-4.1.5-1.x86_64/src/openmpi-4.1.5/opal/mca/pmix/pmix3x/pmix/src/mca/gds/ds12/gds_ds12_lock_pthread.c at line 168
PMIX ERROR: ERROR in file /pub/devel/openmpi/v4.0/openmpi-4.1.5-1.x86_64/src/openmpi-4.1.5/opal/mca/pmix/pmix3x/pmix/src/mca/gds/ds12/gds_ds12_lock_pthread.c at line 168

Comment: also @ThomasMatthews what should I do to run mpi on the a cpp program (I need C++ because I want to use opencv and I don't think that C support opencv)? I tried  with mpicc cppfile.cpp -o cppfile, but I receive some errors:   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /tmp/ccT307Zu.o:lab4cpp.cpp:(.text+0xa2): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()';   I know that .cpp should be compiled with gcc but if I use gcc, then then how could I tell to the program to use mpicc? (If I compile with gcc  then other errors related to MPI occurs)

Comment: I can't answer about `mpi` because I haven't used it.  Maybe somebody other than I can answer it.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I found out that there exists mpic++ command, e.g.  mpic++ cppfile.cpp -o cppfile but the compilation end with an error:  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpi_cxx: No such file or directory;  looks like another thing is missed, this time seems to be related to gcc, do you have about the missed thing - maybe I missed another package?

Comment: before running `mpirun` try `export PMIX_MCA_gds=^ds12`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet the error '... cannot find -lmpi_cxx' still exists after I used your command; but this error appear when I use mpic++, so I don't even reach the mpirun part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected behavior is

```
$ mpicc -Wall prova.c -o prova

$ mpirun -n 2 ./prova
Hello World! I am 1 of 2
Hello World! I am 0 of 2
```

and your code works on my system.
There is no need of Mingw on your PATH. To clean the PATH and test the program in a clean Cygwin enviroment you can run it as

```
$ PATH="/usr/bin/" mpirun -n 2 ./prova
Hello World! I am 0 of 2
Hello World! I am 1 of 2
```

You can also check that the packages are properly installed and nothing is missing with

```
$ cygcheck -c openmpi libopenmpi40
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
libopenmpi40         4.1.5-1        OK
openmpi              4.1.5-1        OK
```

Comment: hello @matzeri;  I already solved the problem related to the C language, but now I have some troubles related to the compilation for the C++ version of the code (with iostream); you can check the comments from the first post (basically, I get an '... cannot find -lmpi_cxx' error when I compile cpp file using mpic++); ALSO, i check the installated status for openmpi packages (as in your example), and for libopenmpi40 that status is Incomplete - how can I fix this?

Comment: update: after I reinstalled the libopenmpi40  package, now the status is OK for both packages but still I get errors when I m using mpic++: it cannot find -lhwloc, -levent_core, -levent_pthreads, -lz

Comment: That is a different thing and it is due to `pkg-config` and  the content of `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/ompi-cxx.pc`. You should install `libhwloc-devel, libevent-devel, zlib-devel`

Comment: I added these packages and now the problem is solved ! thank you ! I'll reward your post, also many thanks to Gilles and Gilles Gouaillardet and   
Thomas Matthews